# Code undoes itself before returning value

Tags: python, recursion

```
from time import sleep
def refit(i, n, c=[]):
 sleep(1)
 print(c)
 if i[:n] != '': refit(i[n:],n,c+[i[:n]])
 sleep(1)
 print(c)
 return c
```

Output when using arguments "Helloo" and 2:

```
[]
['He']
['He', 'll']
['He', 'll', 'oo']
['He', 'll', 'oo']
['He', 'll']
['He']
[]
[]
```

The Array ['He', 'll', 'oo'] should be printed and returned, but the code is undoing itself.
What is happening? I am so confused.

Comment: Instead of calling `refit` recursively, try writing the code so that it calls *any other function* there. Now look again at what happens. Are you still confused? There is nothing in the code that actually causes the value of the local variable `c` to change. Every time you make a recursive call, that is a *separate process* with a *completely independent set* of local variables. Just like it would be *if you called any other function*.

Comment: The **`list`** `['He', 'll', 'oo']` *is* returned, but `refit()` ignores that return value and continues on, returning the original `c=[]` at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a given call to `refit`, you're not changing `c`, so `c` has the same value in the second `print()` that it does in the first `print()`.  All the recursive calls happen in between those two `print` calls.

On the first call, `c` is `[]`:

```
# i = 'Helloo', n = 2, c = []
print(c)  # prints "[]"
if i[:n] != '':
    refit(i[n:],n,c+[i[:n]])  # prints a bunch of other stuff
print(c)  # prints "[]"
return c  # returns []
```

On the second call to `refit` (indicated above by `# prints a bunch of other stuff`) we do:

```
# i = 'lloo', n = 2, c = ['He']
print(c)  # prints "['He']"
if i[:n] != '':
    refit(i[n:],n,c+[i[:n]])  # prints even more stuff
print(c)  # prints "['He']"
return c  # returns ["He"]
```

Our output so far looks like:

```
[]
['He']
(more stuff will go here)
['He']
[]
```

And on and on -- each new recursive call adds another pair of `print` statements in the middle of the previous call.  And each call returns its *original* value of `c`, rather than the new value it got from the recursive call it just made to `refit`.

If you want this function to return the result from the innermost call, then it simply needs to return the result of calling `refit`:

```
def refit(i, n, c=[]):
    return refit(i[n:], n, c + [i[:n]]) if i[:n] else c

print(refit("Helloo", 2))  # ['He', 'll', 'oo']
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean to save the return value from recursive calls to `refit()`?

```py
def refit(i, n, c=[]):
    if i[:n] != '':
        c = refit(i[n:], n, c+[i[:n]])
    return c

c = refit('Helloo',2)
print(c)
```

Output as requested